# Packaged App with full Extension API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I need to create an App, that requires access to some internal Chrome data, like history, bookmarks, apps, top sites, etc.. I don't want to use an Extension, because I would like to display a stand-alone window with a complex UI.

It seems that this data is only available for Legacy Packaged Apps. Is there any way to enable access to full Extension API for a Non-Legacy Packaged App?

P.S. at the moment of writing I'm using Chrome 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, new style Chrome apps are designed to be isolated away from Chrome as much as possible.  You can [create a window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create) in a Chrome extension that is not directly inside the browser by setting the "type" to be "popup".